# Making HttpClient call with self signed client certificate

Tags: .net, ssl, certificate, httpclient

I'm attempting to create an integration with the Swedish payment provider GetSwish. In a stroke of genius, they decided to use client based certificates as authentication instead of hashing and shared secrets like just about every other payment provider on the planet. For some reason they decided to use self signed client certificates instead of getting a bulk deal with comodo, verisign or any other CA out there.

When using HttpClient to connect to the service with the certificate they provide, the underlying HttpClientHandler attempts to verify the validity of the certificate by contacting the CA. This obviously fails since the certificate is self signed. This can be circumvented by installing the certificate in the servers certificate store, which shortcircuits the verification. The application I'm building will be hosted in a PAAS environment where the certificate store is not available.

My current idea is to fork large portions of the System.Net.Http namespace from https://github.com/dotnet/corefx and actually lower the security of the connection by removing the validation to be able to make the requests. Containing financial transactions. It doesn't sit quite right with me.

The comment from GetSwish developer support was "Windows always makes things weird and non standard", followed by no help at all and a good luck.

The following code works when the .p12 file is installed in the computers certificate store:
`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
 X509Certificate2 swishCertificate = new X509Certificate2(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("cert1231181189.p12"), "swish", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);            HttpClientHandler handler = new PartialHttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(swishCertificate);
// Validate the server certificate. Because ofcourse it doesn't work properly either.
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback += ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback;
handler.CheckCertificateRevocationList = false;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);`

Comment: The actual exception is WinHttpException, 0x80072f8f, Security error has occured.